# Using scala constructor to set variable defined in trait

Tags: scala, constructor, traits

If I understand correctly, traits are the closest thing to Java interfaces and class constructors automatically set the variables.

But what if I have a class that extends a trait and has a constructor which sets a variable from the trait, so something like:

```
trait Foo {
    var foo: String
}

class Bar (foo: String) extends Foo { /* ... */ }
```

Where I want the `foo` string of the trait been set when I make a `Bar` object.

The compiler seems to give me errors about this. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Just a note: trait initialization is't a simple thing itself and with variables and overriding you can complect initialization very quickly (I did). Make sure, that you really need it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Bar` must define the abstract `var foo` in `Foo` (would be the same for a `val`). This can be done in the constructor

```
class Bar(var foo: String) extends Foo{...}
```

(of course, it could be done in the body of `Bar` too). By default, constructor parameters will be turned to private `val` if need be, that is if they are used outside the initiailization code, in methods. But you can force the behavior by marking them `val` or `var`, and possibly control the visibility as in

```
class X(protected val s: String, private var i: Int)
```

Here you need a public `var` to implement `Foo`.

Answer (score 33):

```
trait Foo { var foo: String = _ }
class Bar(foo0: String) extends Foo { foo = foo0 }
```

The trait declares an uninitialized var; the class then sets it equal to the input parameter.

Alternatively,

```
trait Foo {
  def foo: String
  def foo_=(s: String): Unit
}
class Bar(var foo: String) extends Foo {}
```

declares the getter/setter pair corresponding to a foo, which are set by the class.