# Reduce boilerplate in class inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance, properties, constructor

I was wondering if there are tricks to reduce boilerplate code in this scenario: inheriting from a class (let's assume that the real world has many more constructor parameters).

```
class Person(name: String, surname: String) {
  def fullname = name + " " + surname
  def header = "Dear " + name  
}

class Employee(val aname: String,
              val asurname: String,
              val role: String) extends Person(aname, asurname) {
  }
```

I have seen some [strategies that involved the use of traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178602/using-scala-constructor-to-set-variable-defined-in-trait).

[Having an abstract base class is not an option](http://scala-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Case-classes-extending-base-class-without-override-td2526136.html).

Answer (score 1):

The question is, do you really have to extend the base class? The trait approach you link to may be enough for your case.

That is, make both `Person` and `Employee` implement a trait with methods `name`, `surname`, `fullname` and `header`:

```
trait PersonLike {
  def name: String
  def surname: String

  def fullname = name + " " + surname
  def header = "Dear " + name
}
```

And have the classes extend the trait:

```
case class Person(name: String, surname: String) extends PersonLike
case class Employee(name: String, surname: String, role: String) extends PersonLike
```

Case classes are probably better for this, but you may use normal classes instead:

```
class Person2(val name: String, val surname: String) extends PersonLike
class Employee2(val name: String, val surname: String, val role: String) extends PersonLike
```

Comment: tnx. this is useful - I have somehow reconsidered the idea of having "property methods" in traits and not just methods as I would have in an `interface`

Answer (score 0):

Using val in a constructor creates new public members. Simplify it using

```
case class Person( name: String, surname: String ) {
  def fullname = name + " " + surname
  def header = "Dear " + name
}

class Employee( _name: String, _surname: String, val role: String )
extends Person( _name, _surname )
```

I also changed Person to be a case class, so the arguments of the constructor become public fields.

If you're looking to reduce the boilerplate, I think that using traits or other tricks simply add more code. So, keep it simple is my suggestion.

Comment: A case class is not necessary to achieve public fields from constructor arguments. `class Person(val name: String, val surname: String)` will also create public fields. The underscores in `Employee` will then become obsolete: `class Employee(name: String, surname: String, val role: String) extends Person(name, surname)`. In `Employee` all three constructor arguments will then be public accessible.